# WebRTC mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

Let's say we have a connection from A to B with webRTC. B sees also his own webcam in a window. 
Is it possible to view the A mouse arrow on the B window where his own webcam is shown?

(so if Alice is connected with Bob, Alice can use his pointer to indicate to Bob where is the spoon in Bob's kitchen).

Comment: There's nothing in WebRTC defining this, you'll have to share that data in a separate channel.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with WebRTC, your solution can be implemented using Javascript. I'm afraid it would be very hard to implement. What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I was just wondering if it was possible, didn't developed yet...i thought it was simple to develop it and just for fun...

Answer (score 2):

Use a [data channel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel) to send mouse pointer coordinates from A to B:

```js
var pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(), pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection();

pc1.onicecandidate = e => pc2.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
pc2.onicecandidate = e => pc1.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
pc1.onnegotiationneeded = e =>
  pc1.createOffer().then(d => pc1.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc2.setRemoteDescription(pc1.localDescription))
  .then(() => pc2.createAnswer()).then(d => pc2.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription))
  .catch(e => console.log(e));

var dc = pc1.createDataChannel("mouse position");
document.onmousemove = e => dc.send(e.x + ", " + e.y);

pc2.ondatachannel = ({channel}) => channel.onmessage = e => console.log(e.data);
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

Then render it in JavaScript on the other end. Low latency is important in peer interactions.

Answer (score 0):

This question has nothing to do with WebRTC: your solution can be implemented using Javascript, but I'm afraid it would be very hard to implement.

I would suggest opening another peer or channel from one client to the other, and sending the mouse pointer coordinates on `canvas.onmousemove` event.